# Emacs Neotree open file in split window

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to open a file from Neotree in a new split window?

I want to achive same functionality as Vim NERDTree shortcuts "i" and "s"

Or is that the wrong approach?

Comment: For other's reference, [OP posted this in Emacs Stack Exchange and got a response](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12249/neotree-open-file-in-split-window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use | for veritcal split and - for horizontal split.